# how to look into gc.garbage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, ctypes

i was testing memory leak and dont have any clue of these garbage comes from

```
<class 'tuple'>,(<class '_ctypes.Array'>,)
<class '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'>,<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_16'>
<class 'getset_descriptor'>,<attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>
<class 'getset_descriptor'>,<attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>
<class 'tuple'>,(<class 'ctypes.c_char_Array_16'>, <class '_ctypes.Array'>, <class '_ctypes._CData'>, <class 'object'>)
<class 'StgDict'>,{'__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>, '_type_': <class 'ctypes.c_char'>, 'raw': <attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>, 'value': <attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>, '__module__': 'ctypes', '_length_': 16}
<class 'getset_descriptor'>,<attribute 'raw' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>
<class 'getset_descriptor'>,<attribute 'value' of 'c_char_Array_16' objects>
```

this is what i used for print the message

```
    strs = []
    for x in gc.garbage:
        try:
            strs.append(str(type(x))+','+str(x))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    print('\n'.join(strs))
```

i want to type for example the tuple's content, any chance?

Comment: What do you mean by "type for example the tuple's content"? If you just want to print the garbage object, `print(x)`.

Comment: i completed the code.

Comment: Could you give a code above the snippet you showed that would lead to similar results, please ? I can't get the same. Is your code above your snippet long ? Does it run a long time before producing the above result ?

Comment: I found the reason,uuid cause this info,it's basically the same question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776291/is-this-a-memory-leak .so i would like to shutdown this question.